# Sort String of Date & Time within array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, time

Given:

```js
[{
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "14:00:00-15:00:00"
}, {
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "10:00:00-12:00:00"
},{
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "12:00:00-14:00:00"
},{
    date: "2020-12-22",
    session: "14:00:00-15:00:00"
}]
```

How to sort by date & session?
because both of them are string, especially session was range of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) requires a function that compares two elements of the array and returns a number: positive, negative or a zero.

Now, since we have to handle date and time, we pick `date` from each component and pick the beginning of the session timestamp by splitting and fetching the first half of the `session` string. We concatenate the date and time to make it easy [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) into milliseconds. The milliseconds can now be used in our comparator to compare the session start time.

```js
const v = [{
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "14:00:00-15:00:00"
}, {
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "10:00:00-12:00:00"
},{
    date: "2020-12-23",
    session: "12:00:00-14:00:00"
},{
    date: "2020-12-22",
    session: "14:00:00-15:00:00"
}];

const parser = ({date, session}) => Date.parse(`${date}T${session.split('-')[0]}`)

v.sort((a, b) => parser(a) - parser(b))

console.log(v)
```

returns

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-12-22",
    "session": "14:00:00-15:00:00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-12-23",
    "session": "10:00:00-12:00:00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-12-23",
    "session": "12:00:00-14:00:00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-12-23",
    "session": "14:00:00-15:00:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using a custom comparison function. Concatenate the strings and use the built in string comparison method.

```
exams.sort( 
    (a,b) => (a.date+a.session).localeCompare(b.date+b.session)
)
```